# python Space invaders clone enemy movement

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

Hello I am still a beginner I am trying to make a space invaders clone, and am trying to make the enemies move but I am having trouble making the individual enemies have a variable name. I may have done this in a weird way I don't know is their anyway I could make this work? This isnt all the code just the code related to the enemies

```
def alien_move(var):
    x = var.xcor()
    var.setx(x - 20)
# enemeies drawing
def enemy(x, y, var):
    global var
    var = turtle.Turtle()
    var.speed(0)
    var.shape("square")
    var.color("red")
    var.penup()
    var.goto(x, y)
    var .direction = "stop"
#FIXME Row of enemies drawing
def row(y):
    global e1
    global e2
    global e3 
    global e4
    global e5
    global e6 
    global e7
    global e8 
    global e9 
    global e10
    global e11
    e1 = None
    e2 = None
    e3 = None
    e4 = None
    e5 = None
    e6 = None
    e7 = None
    e8 = None
    e9 = None
    e10 = None
    e11= None
    enemy(-200,y,e1)
    enemy(-160,y,e2)
    enemy(-120,y,e3)
    enemy(-80,y,e4)
    enemy(-40,y,e5)
    enemy(0,y,e6)
    enemy(40,y,e7)
    enemy(80,y,e8)
    enemy(120,y,e9)
    enemy(160,y,e10)
    enemy(200,y,e11)
# army of rows function
def army(x):
    row_pos = 80
    row(row_pos)
    row_pos+= x
    row(row_pos)
    row_pos+= x
    row(row_pos)
    row_pos+= x
    row(row_pos)
    row_pos+= x
    row(row_pos)
    row_pos+= x

army(40)
while True:
    alien_move(e1)
    # And so on
```

This is probably terrible sorry thank you for your time =)

Edit: Thanks for the help it is working now

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd want to use a [*list*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) of enemies.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Fred Larson in the comments, you want to use a list. [Here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) is the official documentation for lists in Python 3.8.